# xslt input control not setting base on data

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this data that is being used with this xslt file that I can't get the `Selected true` to set the input radio to be checked. Is this the correct logic for checking `test="Selected = true"` to set that attribute?

Data

```
<CustomerGender>
      <CustomerGender>
        <Value>802</Value>
        <Text>Female</Text>
        <Selected>false</Selected>
      </CustomerGender>
      <CustomerGender>
        <Value>803</Value>
        <Text>Male</Text>
        <Selected>false</Selected>
      </CustomerGender>
      <CustomerGender>
        <Value>804</Value>
        <Text>Non-binary</Text>
        <Selected>true</Selected>
      </CustomerGender>
      <CustomerGender>
        <Value>805</Value>
        <Text>Prefer not to answer</Text>
        <Selected>false</Selected>
      </CustomerGender>
      <CustomerGender>
        <Value>806</Value>
        <Text>Other (please specify)</Text>
        <Selected>false</Selected>
      </CustomerGender>
    </CustomerGender>
```

XSLT

```
<div class="col-md-5">
     <label class="control-label">Gender</label>
     <div class="form-group">
          <div class="radio-list">
               <label>
                    <xsl:for-each select ="Customer/CustomerGender/CustomerGender">
                         <input type="radio" name="selectedGender">
                              <xsl:attribute name="id" >
                                <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
                              </xsl:attribute>
                              <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
                              </xsl:attribute>
                              <xsl:if test="Selected = true">
                                <xsl:attribute name="checked">"checked"</xsl:attribute>
                              </xsl:if>
                              <xsl:value-of select="Text"/>
                         </input>
                            &#160;&#160; <br />
                    </xsl:for-each>
               </label>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your line

```
<xsl:if test="Selected = true">
```

works is:

- The test is an xpath expression
- `Selected` is an element name on the child axis
- this part will return a nodelist containing all elements with name `Selected`
- then it will test if the value is the same as the nodelist returned by 'true'

Not what you want. You could do something like

```
<xsl:if test="Selected = true()">
<xsl:if test="Selected">
```

- it will test if the value is a boolean true
- for this [the nodelist has to be converted to boolean, which is true if the nodelist is not empty](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#dt-ebv)
- since in none of your iterations there is a `CustomerGender` without `Selected` it will always be true

So you probably want to change that into

```
<xsl:if test="Selected = 'true'">
```

which will perform a string comparison. An alternative could be

```
<xsl:if test="Selected[1] = 'true'">
```

which will convert the first found element to string (resulting in the text content), then perform the comparison, or

```
<xsl:if test="Selected[1] = true()">
<xsl:if test="Selected[1]">
```

which would convert the first element into a boolean (and now I am lost myself...)

Comment: _then it will test if the value is the same as the boolean value true_  - This is not completely correct. If it was testing the boolean value, it would have to be written `true()`. Since it's written `true` it's comparing against an element named `true` (which would always be false since there are no `true` elements).

Comment: Spot on! I will edit my response.

Comment: so would I want to use `<xsl:if test="Selected = 'true'">`?

Comment: In general you would never write "if XYZ = true()" - you would just do "if XYZ" so it never occurred to me.... Yes, the suggestion is good to use.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure that I understand what you mean?

Comment: @Jefferson - Since you're wanting to do a string comparison, you are correct that you should use `<xsl:if test="Selected = 'true'">`.